# How to force delete a database

Tags: sql-server, windows, ssms

I deleted SSMS a while back and all the SQL related stuff. However, there is a db still lying around in my PC and it isn't deleting. It throws the error that DB is open in SSMS. How do I force delete it?

Answer (score 0):

To close connections:

```
USE [mydb];
ALTER DATABASE [mydb] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Then drop:

```
USE master;
DROP DATABASE [mydb];
```

Comment: The database is File type. How do I open it in VScode SQL